# Passing views from abstract activity

Tags: java, android, inheritance, abstract-class

I'm trying to pass some views to ClassA from abstract ClassB, so that ClassA can use: `ClassA extends ClassB`

Instead of using something like this for each view I'd like to be inherited/passed on:

```
protected View getView1() {
    return view1;
}
```

I want a bulk way to let ClassX (in this case, ClassA) know which views it should be using. But keep some views private to ClassB to use for itself.

The code below does work, but is it okay to do it this way? or is there a better way?

```
public abstract class ClassB extends Activity {

    abstract void useTheseViews(View view1, View view2);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        View view1 = findViewById(R.id.view1);
        View view2 = findViewById(R.id.view2);
        useTheseViews(view1, view2);

        View view3 = findViewById(R.id.view3);
        view3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 // do something independent here
             }
         });
    }
}

public class ClassA extends ClassB {

    private View view1, view2;

    @Override
    void useTheseViews(View view1, View view2) {
        this.view1 = view1;
        this.view2 = view2;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            view1.setOnClickListener(..);
            view2.setOnClickListener(..);
    }
}
```

Reason? ClassA and ClassX use the same base layout, but do different functions on the same views.

My ClassB holds a base layout and initializes the views (buttons, switches..), and uses some of the views for itself regardless of what class extends it.

Comment: Why don't you just use fragments? It's a better way to compose your Activities.

Comment: It will help us better understand what you are doing if you show some screenshots or mockups of each screen. As Anix mentioned, it might be better to use Fragments instead of Activities.

Comment: with Fragments you compose your activity in a modular way, with inheritance you compose your activity in a hierarchical way, I don't see how fragments would solve the problem here

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way

```
public abstract class ClassB extends Activity {

    private View view1, view2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        view1 = findViewById(R.id.view1);
        view2 = findViewById(R.id.view2);

    }

    protected View getView1(){
        return view1;
    }

    protected View getView2(){
        return view2;
    }
}

public class ClassA extends ClassB {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getView1().setOnClickListener(..);
        getView2().setOnClickListener(..);
    }
}
```

and if you don't want to create protected getter for each view, use a holder class

```
public abstract class ClassB extends Activity {

    protected class ViewHolder {

        public final View view1, view2;

        public ViewHolder(){
            view1 = findViewById(R.id.view1);
            view2 = findViewById(R.id.view2);
        }
    }

    private ViewHolder viewHolder;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

    }

    protected ViewHolder getViewHolder(){
        return viewHolder;
    }
}

public class ClassA extends ClassB {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getViewHolder().view1.setOnClickListener(..);
        getViewHolder().view2.setOnClickListener(..);
    }
}
```

the way I'm suggesting seems coherent with OOP, also, if you say ClassA and ClassB I would assume that ClassA extends ClassB. What happens if you want to create a third class that extends ClassA?

Comment: Such issues are preferably solved with Fragments, I would have agreed with your answer if Fragments were not there.

Comment: feel free to post answer to show how you would solve with fragments